# How to create shortcut that will kill process for buffer with fixed name

Tags: shell, process, r

I have code like this to run R command from Emacs:

```
(defun call-r-command (command-list)
  "run R command in shell buffer window

  if there is displayed buffer that have shell it will use that window"
  (let* ((name "*R*")
         (new-buffer (get-buffer-create name))
         (old-buff (get-buffer name))
         (script-proc-buffer
          (apply 'make-comint-in-buffer
                 "script"
                 new-buffer
                 "c:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/R.exe"
                 nil
                 command-list))
         (old-window (if old-buff (get-buffer-window old-buff)))
         (window (or old-window
                     (get-window-with-mode '(comint-mode eshell-mode))))
       (script-proc (get-buffer-process script-proc-buffer)))
    (if window
        (set-window-buffer window new-buffer)
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window new-buffer))))
```

I use this function to build R package:

```
(defun build-r-package ()
  (interactive)
  (call-r-command `("CMD" "INSTALL" ,(git-root-repo))))
```

for this I don't need to kill the process but I need this when I run process that still running (I call this function that run shiny server):

```
(defun shiny ()
  "run shiny R application in shell buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let ((R (concat "shiny::runApp('" default-directory "')")))
    (call-r-command `("-e" ,R "--no-save"))))
```

So who can I make it so when I press <kbd>q</kbd> it will kill the process when I'm in `*R*` buffer? Do I need to use set-process-sentinel function? Do I need to create minor mode to add <kbd>q</kbd> into `*R*` buffer?

I completely don't know how to make this work. Any help is appreciated. If you provide code that will make it work, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `script-proc-buffer` will always be `new-buffer` since that is an existing buffer when `make-comint-in-buffer` is called.

To bind `kill-process` to the key sequence <kbd>q</kbd> make it somehow interactive and use `local-set-key` with the wanted buffer current, e.g.:

```el
(with-current-buffer script-proc-buffer
  (local-set-key "q" (lambda () (interactive) (kill-process))))
```

I would highly recommend not to use "q" as key sequence but something like `(kbd "C-c q")`.

Applied to your example:

```el
(defun call-r-command (command-list)
  "run R command in shell buffer window

  if there is displayed buffer that have shell it will use that window"
  (let* ((name "*R*")
         (new-buffer (get-buffer-create name))
         (old-buff (get-buffer name))
         (script-proc-buffer
          (apply 'make-comint-in-buffer
                 "script"
                 new-buffer
                 "c:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/bin/R.exe"
                 nil
                 command-list))
         (old-window (if old-buff (get-buffer-window old-buff)))
         (window (or old-window
                     (get-window-with-mode '(comint-mode eshell-mode))))
       (script-proc (get-buffer-process script-proc-buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer script-proc-buffer
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c q") (lambda () (interactive) (kill-process))))
    (if window
        (set-window-buffer window new-buffer)
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window new-buffer))))
```

DISCLAIMER: Since I don't use R I have not tested the code. Please test and report back.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I've added small modification, I've killed previous process if there is one running for old-buffer. Because this will happen when I've run server and want to build the package when it's still running. If I didn't do this, I will have hidden process with server running or some kind of error.

Comment: @jcubic Do you know the [ess project](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html)? I do not use it but I think they already have R-sessions.

Comment: I have it installed and I think I have it enable for R buffer, not sure if it have shiny (web server) support.

Comment: You can run a shiny app from an ESS buffer, no extra configuration is needed

Comment: Does it open chrome browser when running shiny? I just added this before I've read  your comment.

Comment: @Tyler Note: jcubic forgot to add `@Tyler`.

Comment: It should open your default browser when you call it